# Reaction constant contains one of the reactants

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I need to provide the reaction rate functions of a system of reactions consisting of 5 reactions. One of them has the form: $$r_1 = \frac{k_a}{K_D + \frac{K_D}{K_I}X_4}\cdot X_2\cdot X_4.$$ I do not know how to handle the term of the reaction constant of this reaction rate function given that one of the reactants, $X_4,$ is inside the constant. What I ultimately need, is to write a differential equation concerning the reaction dynamics. How can I handle this problem ?

Comment: What's to handle? You know your concentrations: these are $X_1,\,X_2$, etc. You know your rates. Well, the derivative of this is that, and so on.

Comment: If that's the rate expression, then it is. If $X_4$ is a constant value (i.e. the system has enormous amounts of it, then you can form one with a pseudo 'rate constant'

Comment: @user129173 sounds like you're dealing with a multiple reaction problem. What are the 5 reactions and individual rates given?

Comment: Reaction rates of complex multistep reactions in context of a system of linked reactions generally does not have form $\text{Rate} = k \cdot [\ce{A}]^a \cdot [\ce{B}]^b$, so $X_4$ is not inside the reaction rate constant. // See e.g. [H2 + Br2 -> 2 HBr](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/81063/formation-of-hydrogen-bromide-does-the-concept-of-order-apply-to-this-reactio)