# Are there exceptions to the rate law for elementary reactions?

Tags: kinetics

According to several authentic sources (for example, [ChemLibreTexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Kinetics/03%3A_Rate_Laws/3.02%3A_Reaction_Mechanisms/3.2.01%3A_Elementary_Reactions)), for elementary reactions, the order is equal to molecularity according to the rate law.

---

**Example:** For an elementary reaction $$\ce{aA +bB -> cC +dD}$$ the rate of reaction is given by $$R = k [\ce{A}]^{a} [\ce{B}]^{b},$$ where $k$ is the rate constant and $[\cdot]$ represents concentration.

---

I am aware that, in real solutions, concentrations are replaced by activities; however, the structure of the *real* rate law is still same as that obtained from the *ideal* rate law.

I wanted to know if there are any exceptions to this. Is there an elementary reaction for which the rate law is *not* obeyed, and the molecularity is *not* equal to order?

Comment: I think it would hold perfectly, if not for things like fast two-step vs one step ambiguity.

Comment: Your first equation tells us *nothing* about the way the species react other than $a$ moles of $[A]$ plus $b$ of $[B]$ react and so on. The example by Poutnik below for $H_2/Br_2$ clearly shows this where the rate $R$ is not of the form you quote even when $a=b=1$. Order is an experimental quantity only found with great difficulty. If you like, the connection between $R$ and your chemical equation is  fiction and based on assumptions about the mechanism as a way or trying to fit mechanism to experiment.

Comment: @porphyrin the rate law helps us in this regard; if it is known that a reaction is elementary, we can determine the order theoretically using just the stoichiometry of the reaction.

Comment: @anata , 'if is known that the reaction is elementary' this is just the point, you do not know this unless an experiment is done, even atom+atom.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that, for elementary reactions, the reaction rate order is equal to molecularity.

The point is, for $a + b \gt 3$ ( and often for $a + b = 3$ or even $a + b = 2$ ), the reaction is not elementary.

Typical case is $\ce{Br2 + H2 -> 2 HBr}$. It looks like it may be an elementary reaction, but it is not. It has the loopbacked chain reaction schema. Its reaction rate is [a rational function with some non-integer exponents](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/81063/35806):

> $$r= \frac{k[\ce{H2}][\ce{Br2}]^{1/2}}{1 + j[\ce{HBr}]/[\ce{Br2}]}$$

( $k$ and $j$ are rate constants for particular reactions steps withing the reaction kinetic schema. )

Another exception are reactions of the zeroth order, with the rate not depending on the analyte concentration, typically photolytic reactions.

Comment: As far as I know, all zero order reactions are complex (and not elementary) reactions, these do not make an exception to the rate law.

Comment: Hmm, $\ce{Cl2 ->[h\nu] 2 Cl}$ does not seem complex. at least far from the steady state when recombination matches photolysis.

Comment: What is the rate expression for the reaction $\ce{Cl2 ->[h\nu] 2 Cl}$? Actually, even my first thought was photodissociation reactions. I wanted to confirm if this is the case.

Comment: R_forward = k. I[W/m2], net rate R = k.I - k2 . (p(Cl2))^2

Comment: Could you please cite this?

Comment: I cannot, I always fail in referencing particular neurons. The forward part is typical for photolysis, the recombination is the elementary reaction.

Comment: @Poutnik what is j?

Comment: The reaction $\ce{Br2 + H2 -> 2 HBr}$ seems to be a chain-reaction rather than an elementary reaction based on web search. This doesn't seem to be an exception to the rate law. I think [this reference](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/j100826a006) clarifies it.

Comment: I have not said it is an elementary reaction, I was just hinting it may look like one. As, OTOH, $\ce{I2 + H2 -> 2 HI}$ is not a chain reaction, but elementary reaction, forming $\ce{I2 \bond{...}H2}$ activated complex. // 
j is rate constant for particular steps in the reaction schema.